# Is there a windows api version of swprintf_s() that doesn't use the microsoft CRT?

Tags: c, winapi

I need a strictly windows api function similar to `swprintf_s()` that doesn't use the microsoft CRT

Comment: It looks like `StringCchPrintf`depends on `_vsnprintf_s` in the CRT even when using the library form, so this won't help you. Unfortunately I think your only pure Win32 option is `wsprintf` which has no buffer over-run protection.

Comment: As Jonathan Potter commented, there unfortunately doesn't appear to be such a thing. You'd apparently need to create your own `_vsnprintf` and `_vsnwprintf` to get `StringCchPrintf` working. Why avoid the CRT?

Comment: Be warned that if you are using Visual Studio, applications that aren't linked to the CRT may intermittently crash on startup for no readily apparent reason.  (This appears to be a new problem; applications that I've been using for years without difficulty started crashing intermittently sometime in the last few months.)

Comment: @Harry: That's interesting news. Since I recently wrote an application that doesn't link the CRT, I'm getting a bit uneasy. Do you have a link to additional information? Is it related to a specific OS version, or a particular Visual Studio release?

Comment: @IInspectable: no idea, sorry, this is just something I've experienced myself.  Actually I've been meaning to post a question on the subject.  It's possible that I'm doing something wrong, but I don't see what it could be; and as near as I can tell, the crash occurs before Windows even calls my entry point.  Unfortunately the problem is difficult to reproduce, so I don't have much useful information.

Comment: @IInspectable: on second thoughts, going back over the sequence of events, and given how intermittent the problem is, it is possible that it isn't a new issue but rather is an issue that only affects 64-bit applications.  I can't be sure though.

Comment: @ChronoKitsune To make the app size smaller. I think I was confusing the C Runtime library with the microsoft C Runtime library. I want to avoid the C Runtime library. I don't mind including the microsoft C Runtime library. Can you include the microsoft C Runtime library without including the whole C Runtime library?

Comment: @Rm32a: the Microsoft C runtime library is, as the name implies, Microsoft's version of the C runtime library.  They aren't really two different things.

Comment: @Rm32a Harry is correct. Since you mentioned app size, what mode are you compiling in, and what is the app size currently? Compiling in Release mode will reduce the app size, assuming you're not using it already (debugging information requires extra space, not to mention optimizations are typically disabled by default in Debug mode). However, all of that likely won't reduce the size of your code terribly much. Are you perhaps accidentally compiling a console app?

Comment: @Harry: I'm sorry to hijack this question, but I'm curious (for obvious reasons). Could this crash be related to anti-malware software running in the system, or did this happen to you on a clean install as well? I used to have issues with a CRT-less application myself, to the point, where *<Product X by notorious vendor of security solutions>* immediately purged the binary, as soon as the linker was done.

Comment: @IInspectable: unfortunately, at the time I was too busy to make proper notes, so I can't confirm whether or not I've seen this happen on a machine with no AV.  (We use Symantec Endpoint Protection, currently 12.1.5.)  I do have a single machine currently exhibiting the problem (SEP is installed) and I'm trying to debug, it seems to go wrong very early during process startup.  I do intend to post a question once I've got some more information, in the meantime perhaps you would like to email me directly?  See my profile.

Comment: @IInspectable: http://stackoverflow.com/q/30659232/886887